# Typescript- handling undefined from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, type-conversion, undefined

I am writing a web application in typescript and jQuery (using the Definitely Typed jQuery definition files).  One of the issues I keep running into is that many of the jQuery functions return a number or undefined.  This throws off the typescript compiler, and so I've reverted to using a utility function:

```
function zero_if_undefined(value: number | undefined): number {
    if value === undefined:
        return 0;
    return value;
}
```

Then something like:

```
let width: number = zero_if_undefined($('#myEle').innerWidth());
```

Is there a better (or even inline) way of accomplishing the same goal?  Or is this the best way?

Comment: `let width: number = $('#myEle').innerWidth() || 0;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally follow one simple approach,You could try using

```
 let width: number = $('#myEle').innerWidth() || 0;
```

If you want to enhance zero_if_undefined method try same in method.

```
function zero_if_undefined(value: number | undefined): number {
  return value || 0 
}
```

FYI,

```
 +!!undefined is also 0.
```